# Cannot add node js modules to git due to long path error on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, git

I added email-template node.js module to my project. It has automatically added dependencies with it. A set of them can not be added to git due to long path error on windows.

One file of them:

```
D:/t/nodeTest/node_modules/email-templates/node_modules/juice/node_modules/web-resource-inliner/node_modules/uglify-js/node_modules/yargs/node_modules/cliui/node_modules/right-align/node_modules/align-text/node_modules/kind-of/node_modules/is-buffer/.travis.yml
```

I noticed that there are lot of dependencies.

Also I tried to use `npm dedupe` to make flat paths. But it also gave `unavoidable conflict` warnings for these files.

Is there any method to add these files to git? Or make file paths short? Or make dependencies flat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally do not want to include source files for dependencies to your source control system, as these are not part of your project.

You should rather add the node_modules folder to the gitignore file and make sure you add all of your dependencies to package.json (say, via npm install --save)

Whenever you (or anyone else) want to run the project, say after cloning/forking it or simply pulling the latest commit, you just npm install to download all required dependencies (i.e. let npm handle external dependencies, not git).

Let me stress it again, do not track files for external dependencies, that definitely isn't the right way to go.

Comment: Many would disagree with this advice. You should store everything you need to build your project in 10-15 years. And you should certainly assume that your external dependencies will be no longer maintained or available by that point.

Comment: @JTolley I disagree you do not want to check these dependencies into your source control, I minimise the amount of dependencies and ensure that whatever ones I use they are actively maintained.

Comment: Well, "many" would (and often do) do incredibly stupid things.

Comment: Specifically though, Version Control is not intended as a backup system. You want your git repo to be as lean and clean as possible. You can use a backup system or external mirror for anything else and include directions in the project's readme.

This is pretty much a good and accepted practice.

Unless you're also suggesting committing the source files of the operating system your project is intended to be built and run on. Because, you know, it might be eventually get decommissioned ;)

Comment: There's a different between build tools, environment requirements, and source required by your application. Once you've installed any requirements listed in your projects readme and configured your environment, you should be able to check out your repo to any folder you want, as many times as you want and build it. Without assuming that any external resources outside of your control are still available. That includes npm.

Comment: I made a point of not calling the answer stupid, because it isn't. But it is short sighted. If you work in an environment where short sighted is enough for you then by all means. Don't create work for yourself when you can rely on npm. If you work in a corporate environment where your project could well be still running a decade from now, then you're opening you and your company up to be bitten in the backside later on

Comment: Thanks all of you. I got points, you all said. This problem will also affects for other build systems like maven. We can't keep all dependent files in git. But there is a risk in that case. How ever if we use popular and active dependencies, we can keep dependencies separate. Also it is better to keep a backup of these dependencies somewhere.